# DELETE index command returns varying JSON objects

Tags: elasticsearch, rust, response, http-delete, reqwest

(ES 8.6.2, W10)

In Insomnia, when I try to delete a non-existent index, using command DELETE and url https://localhost:9500/my_test_index, I always seem to get a JSON object like this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
    ...
    "status": 404
}
```

Similarly when I do the above in Python, using `requests`, I get the above response.

But when I run a `reqwest` request (in Rust) doing that same request I sometimes get the above but often get this:

```
{
    "acknowledged": true
}
```

The reason I'm doing this is to delete the index if it exists. Either 200 or 404 would therefore be acceptable status codes. But if I get "acknowledged", true or false, I don't know what that means: it's `true` even if the index doesn't exist.

This is all happening on a local machine, with one shard. At the current time there are no other indices in my shard. When I create this index, it has a yellow status. So my server/shard seem to be healthy enough.

Can anyone suggest why this might be happening? Might "acknowledged" mean in this case that the server is busy (on a previous command)? Is it possible that Rust's `reqwest` code works faster than Python?

**Edit**
I seem to have detected a pattern: I run the caller Python program, which calls the Rust module, and I get this unexplained result, i.e. `response.text()` is "{"acknowledged": true}". Then I run it again and I get an expected response, with "error" and "status" keys. Then I run again and I get the unexplained result, and so on. I.e. there seems to be an alternation between the 2.

**Edit2**
If I get this "{ "acknowledged": true }" `response.text()`, and then repeat the command (whether or not after waiting for 1 ms), it seems that I always get the expected type of response (with "status" key) on the second attempt.

It's funny how this only seems to occur using Rust, not Python. I wonder what the explanation can be. Reading around I see some stuff about "nodes" possibly taking time to respond in the kind of way you expect. Quite strange: would like to know if an expert can suggest what might be going on.

**Rust code**
As requested. My Rust code takes place inside a utilities function, which uses the `duang` crate to permit optional/named parameters:

```
duang!(
    pub fn reqwest_call<T: serde::de::DeserializeOwned + std::fmt::Debug>(url: &str, method: reqwest::Method = reqwest::Method::GET, timeout: u64 = 5_000, 
        acceptable_status_codes: Vec<u16> = vec![200], content_type: &str = "application/json", body_str: &str = "") 
        -> Result<T, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        let mut error_details = format!(
            "=> url was |{url}|\n=> method was {method}\n=> content type was {content_type}\n=> timeout was {timeout}\n=> body\n|");
        if body_str.len() <= 200 {
            error_details.push_str(body_str);
        }
        else {
            error_details.push_str(&(body_str.to_string()[0..200]));
            error_details.push_str("...");
        };
        error_details.push_str("|\n\n");
        let response_result = get_reqwest_client(timeout)?
        .request(method, url)
        .header("Content-type", content_type)
        .body(body_str.to_string())
        .basic_auth("mike12", Some("mike12"))
        .send(); 
        let response = match response_result {
            Ok(response) => response,
            Err(e) => {
                error!("{e}\n{error_details}\n{}", Backtrace::force_capture());
                return Err(Box::new(e))
            }
        };
        ...
```

... this in turn calls another utility `get_reqwest_client` which delivers a `reqwest.blocking.Client` with the specified timeout. The timeout is currently 5 seconds (see default parameter in the above). No timeout error is happening. If it was, `send` would send us to the `Err` branch in the above and there'd be no examination of any returned JSON object.

The actual Rust call to my utility method:

```
    let url = format!("{ES_URL}/{}", &op_handler.index_name);
    #[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
    struct DeleteResponse {
        status: usize
    }
    let acceptable_status_codes: Vec<u16> = vec![200, 404];
    let _: DeleteResponse = match reqwest_call!(&url, reqwest::Method::DELETE,
        acceptable_status_codes=acceptable_status_codes) {
        Ok(response) => {
            ...
        Err(e) => {
            ... 
            /* this part will reveal the message of error "e": namely 
that the JSON does not have a key "status", which it must have: otherwise
it can't be interpreted (cast) as a `DeleteResponse` `struct`.*/
```

Answer (score -1):

In most cases you will get with 404 or 200 with `"acknowledged": true`. You will get `"acknowledged": false` when index is found and the delete operation is initiated but it takes too long because master node is busy and  cannot process the request within the specified timeout. This behavior is not client-specific and there should be no difference between python and rust responses unless you do something different in your `request` call.

I tried reproducing your situation, unfortunately you omitted some pretty important parts of your code but if you put a print statement after `.send();` I get something like this:

```
Ok(
  Response { 
    url: Url { 
      scheme: "http", 
      cannot_be_a_base: false, 
      username: "", 
      password: None, 
      host: Some(Domain("localhost")),
      port: Some(9500), 
      path: "/test", 
      query: None, 
      fragment: None 
   }, 
   status: 404, 
   headers: {"x-elastic-product": "Elasticsearch", "content-type": "application/json", "content-length": "353"} 
  }
)
```

And if I put another print statement after match and take a look at response.bytes() you will see something like this:

```
{
    "error":
    {
        "root_cause":
        [
            {
                "type": "index_not_found_exception",
                "reason": "no such index [test]",
                "resource.type": "index_or_alias",
                "resource.id": "test",
                "index_uuid": "_na_",
                "index": "test"
            }
        ],
        "type": "index_not_found_exception",
        "reason": "no such index [test]",
        "resource.type": "index_or_alias",
        "resource.id": "test",
        "index_uuid": "_na_",
        "index": "test"
    },
    "status": 404
}
```

So if I replace ... at the end of reqwest with something like

```
    Ok(serde_json::from_slice(response.bytes().unwrap().as_ref()).unwrap())
```

I get back `Ok(DeleteResponse { status: 404 })` in the caller. It seems like everything is working as expected. What do you get?

Comment: Thanks, see edit. The timeout with this client is 5 s. But no timeout is occurring either in Python or Rust. I don't understand what you mean when you say "you will get with 404 or 200". I'm saying that very often I get a JSON object returned with **only one key**, namely "acknowledged". There is NO "status" key at all.

Comment: @mikerodent by status I meant HTTP Status Code. If index doesn't exist you should always get code 404 (unless you are using wildcards), but that's the whole different story. If index exist you should get 200 and JSON with the acknowledged field. I don't see anything special in this method, how do you call it? Are you sure the index indeed doesn't exist?

Comment: `response.text()` is "{"acknowledged":true}". That's it. The index does not exist.

Comment: So, how does the reqwest_call look like? What do you pass as url and method parameters? Can you "sniff" the request that is getting sent to elasticsearch?

Comment: Er, I put both the url and the method as the *very first line* of my question! But I'm adding the call line.

Comment: I tired reproducing it based that bits and pieces that you were willing to provide, and everything seems to work as expected.